# Analyzing a .Net application without VisualStudio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, debugging

Is there a simple, free way to analyze .Net code (set breakpoint, see stack traces, see running threads) without Visual Studio?  Note that I don't need to compile the code, just analyze how it works.  I have both source code and binaries but I don't have a Visual Studio license.  Unfortunately, the solution file gives several error when I try Visual Studio Express.

EDIT:  I may be able to get most of the projects in the solution to load, but I don't see an option for "Debug|Attach to process".  Is this not available in Visual Studio Express?

Comment: What errors does Express give?

Comment: "Solution folders are not supported in this version of the application.  Solution folder 'x' will be displayed as unavailable."

Comment: Everybody that uses the Express edition eventually concludes that the hassle isn't worth the license fee.  It is only free if your time is free.  This is by design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried [SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/)?

Answer (score 2):

If I remember right, **[MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/)** is free, runs on Windows, and supports debugging. I'm not sure if this only works with some languages, but you can give it a go!

**Edit**: Just [checked](http://monodevelop.com/Download/What%27s_new_in_MonoDevelop_2.2#Feature_Matrix), and MonoDevelop supports debugging of managed code in its Windows version.

Answer (score 1):

[Windbg](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/debugging/default.mspx), allthough its probably too low level for you.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to statically peek at it dont forget reflector http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/

the worlds best source browser - and it doesnt even need the source

Answer (score 0):

You're probably missing some required DLLs, causing VS Express to give you an error.

Please post the exact error message(s).

Answer (score 0):

[Visual Studio Shell (Integrated Mode)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=2e9a8c35-eb3d-43eb-9122-a5ec195cd7bb&displaylang=en) allows you to attach to a process. This edition is basically:

- Does not include any support for *particular* languages, but
- Allows extensions to be installed to, for example, add support for a new language
- Allows you to attach to a process using the managed or native code debugger